# Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location - in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, flutter

I am installing Flutter and everything is good except one thing, specified above.

Flutter doctor says this:

$ flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.228], locale nl-NL)
    • Flutter version 0.7.3 at C:\Flutter\flutter_windows_new\flutter
    • Framework revision 3b309bda07 (13 days ago), 2018-08-28 12:39:24 -0700
    • Engine revision af42b6dc95
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-ccb16f7282

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\iwijsman\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 27.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 28.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b02)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.2
    • Flutter plugin version 28.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 182.4323.44

[√] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Pixel 2 • FA83P1A01724 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

I've added the requested path to variables and in Android studio, the plugins are installed and applied but I still get this error.

please help me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: 46k times views but only 13 upvotes. Kindly give appreciations by upvotes If you are logged in.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As mentioned in the message it is optional and only used for specific tasks.

You can install it from Android Studio

Menu > Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK (left side of the dialog) > SDK Tools (tab)

Ensure that this line is enabled

[image]

With [OK] it should be installed.

Answer (score 47):

The same problem faced me, but trying the above solution was not helpful. So I tried another thing:

1. Open File
2. Select settings from the File menu
3. Select Languages & frameworks from the left panel
4. Select Flutter
5. Then from the right panel choose the location of your flutter SDK

The location of flutter SDK is where you copied or cloned the code. In my case it was like the following:[image]
If the specified location contains the flutter SDK, the version section will contain your flutter version. If not, the version section will not contain any versions and there will be a message in the bottom of the setting dialog saying:

> Flutter SDK Is Not Found In The Specified Location

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct. In fact Android Studio lost path to flutter after update not to DartSDK

Answer (score 34):

The path to the SDK should be to the main Flutter folder (**e.g.** `C:\src\flutter` and not to the `bin` folder as set in the Environment Variable Path.

Comment: If you are sure you followed all the other steps correctly, chances are.. this is the issue.

Comment: I can't believe this is what I got stuck on

Answer (score 2):

1. create an android project and see everything works fine.
2. if Gradle sync problem with kotline : File -> Settings -> Kotlin Compiler -> Target JVM Version Changing to 1.8 fixed the issue.

If everything run fine as android project then proced:

3. File -> Settings ->Languages & frameworks->Flutter.
4. select flutter sdk path as src\flutter and ok
5. if step 4 not works then select path src\flutter\bin;

Note:if android 10.0 not work then try it with 9.0;

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly specify the path of the Flutter installation. To find the path, run in your command line:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

The second  line of the output should be the path:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.488], locale en-US)
   --- THIS LINE CONTAINS THE PATH---
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at C:\src\flutter\flutter_windows_2.0.6-stable\flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (6 days ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    ...
```

Enter the path into Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter folder put on dekstop and try to again to set flutter sdk path

check this also..

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows