# Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Unhandled exception: Crash when compiling null, at character offset null:

Tags: flutter, dart

When creating a project, it immediately gives the following error
flutter doctor - OK!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYQMN.png)

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Unhandled exception:
Crash when compiling null,
at character offset null:
Unsupported operation: _ExplicitNamedTypeBuilder.registerInferredType
#0      TypeBuilder.registerInferredType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:350:5)
#1      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.finalizeSuperInitializingFormals.performRecoveryForErroneousCase (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:355:23)
#2      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.finalizeSuperInitializingFormals (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:375:14)
#3      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.inferFormalTypes (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:290:9)
#4      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.inferTypes (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:263:5)
#5      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:149:19)
#6      SourceLoader.performTopLevelInference (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2358:19)
#7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:407:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:68:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:572:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1210:11)
<asynchronous suspension>


#0      TypeBuilder.registerInferredType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/type_builder.dart:350:5)
#1      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.finalizeSuperInitializingFormals.performRecoveryForErroneousCase (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:355:23)
#2      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.finalizeSuperInitializingFormals (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:375:14)
#3      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.inferFormalTypes (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:290:9)
#4      DeclaredSourceConstructorBuilder.inferTypes (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_constructor_builder.dart:263:5)
#5      InferableTypeBuilder.inferType (package:front_end/src/fasta/builder/omitted_type_builder.dart:149:19)
#6      SourceLoader.performTopLevelInference (package:front_end/src/fasta/source/source_loader.dart:2358:19)
#7      KernelTarget.buildOutlines.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/kernel/kernel_target.dart:532:14)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      withCrashReporting (package:front_end/src/fasta/crash.dart:122:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      IncrementalCompiler.computeDelta.<anonymous closure> (package:front_end/src/fasta/incremental_compiler.dart:407:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     IncrementalCompiler.compile (package:vm/incremental_compiler.dart:68:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:572:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     listenAndCompile.<anonymous closure> (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:1210:11)
<asynchronous suspension>
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flp6x.png)

android studio reinstall didn't help.

in my case the solutions from this page do not work
[StatelessWidget : Classes can only extend other classes.dart(extends_non_class) - issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711913/statelesswidget-classes-can-only-extend-other-classes-dartextends-non-class)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got a similar error when:

- the physical memory on my laptop was full, and I just needed to free it up a little
- I just updated the Flutter version to the latest

Comment: I'll probably try to change the versions too

Answer (score 0):

You can also try running `flutter clean` in the terminal, and then `flutter pub get`. This works often in these kinds of situations.

Comment: I already did.  did not help