# Flutter SDK Is Not Found In The Specified Location

Tags: flutter

I'm extremely frustrated right now after I updated Android Studio to have the latest Flutter and Dart Plugins. Now it tells me "No FLutter SDK configured" and when I give it the SKD path it just says, "Flutter SDK Is Not Found In The Specified Location." The Dart plugin works fine.

I have looked for an answer for hours and nothing works. I've downloaded the NDK, flutter doctor works perfectly, and I've tried set the SDK path to pretty much every file inside my flutter folder (inside /Documents).

Any tips?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, you may find my answer located here helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939783/960184

Comment: very useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57221154/9130109

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location - in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259764/flutter-sdk-is-not-found-in-the-specified-location-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Go to - Configure -> Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK > SDK Tools, and search for flutter. You will get flutter SDK for Android.

If you are using Visual studio, also install plugins for flutter in Visual Studio.

» Steps:

1. Download Flutter SDK: [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux)
2. Extract Flutter:

```
tar xf ~/Downloads/flutter_linux_v1.7.8+hotfix.4-stable.tar.xz
```

3. Path export for particular terminal:

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

4. Permanent Path export:
   Open bashrc file: Go to home directory terminal -> `nano ~/.bashrc`
   Write at end of file:

```
export PATH=" [PATH_Where_Flutter SDK Extracted] /flutter/bin:$PATH"
example: export PATH="/home/sid/0_aaa_iauro/Flutter/s/flutter/bin:$PATH"
```

5. Run the following command to see if there are any dependencies you need to
   install to complete setup:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

6. Add Flutter extension to vs-code.
7. Locate Flutter SDK.
8. Make New project in flutter:

```
flutter create Project_name
```

» Important Links:

1. [Linux Install](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux)
2. [Getting Started with Flutter on Linux for Android [Beginner Tutorial]](https://jonathanmh.com/getting-started-with-flutter-on-linux-for-android-beginner-tutorial/)
3. [How To Install And Setup Flutter On Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)](https://www.techomoro.com/how-to-install-and-setup-flutter-on-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-bionic-beaver/)
4. [Part 2-A: Install Flutter in Windows – Step by Step Guide](http://flutter-tutorials.com/install-flutter-in-windows/)
5. Check for path variable (bashrc file):
   [Flutter – Step by Step Installation on Linux – Ubuntu](https://www.tutorialkart.com/flutter/flutter-install-on-linux-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a fresh new Android Studio install as me, try installing missing packages for SDK support in Android Studio as described here: https://ladwhocodes.blogspot.com/2019/02/fix-flutter-sdk-not-found-in-specified-location.html

> Go to Menu > Tools > SDK Manager > Android SDK (left side of the dialog) > SDK Tools (tab).
>   Select 'Support Repository' and 'NDK' checkboxes.
>   Click OK.
>   It will prompt you to install some dependencies. Install them.

Answer (score 0):

What happen to me was because there is a space in my android sdk path (which is my username). I copy to C:\android\sdk and problem gone. Probably the space cause issue to NDK thus affect to Flutter sdk.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was caused by local changes to the flutter git repo. On command line, everything worked, but in Android Studio it failed to detected the flutter sdk which caused all flutter commands to fail (even though flutter bin dir is in my path). The local changes were probably caused by trying out the beta version of flutter and returning to stable afterwards.

solution: delete flutter dir and redownload (I actually reverted all changes using the `git clean` command)