# Flutter SDK is not found in specified location

Tags: flutter

I have been worked with the Flutter SDK path: /Users/mai/Library/Android/sdk but now I can not create a new Flutter project due to the message "Flutter SDK is not fount in the specified location".
I have checked in SDK Manager and that is the path shown in there as well.
Anyone has any idea how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

[My screen for creating new flutter project[][1]]

[image: 1]

Comment: The image you attached is a bit hidden and secondly, we have to see the result of `flutter doctor` run from the terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location - in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259764/flutter-sdk-is-not-found-in-the-specified-location-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

This is the android sdk! Not the flutter sdk.
To change the flutter sdk location open file menu **> settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter** and set the flutter sdk path to where flutter sdk is stored on your computer.
If you don't have the flutter sdk you can download it here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos

Answer (score 0):

just like above message said, that path is for android sdk, where does this message appears to you? Normally when you do an installation of flutter you need to unzip it on some root folder, and provide the environment variable for that in the bash that you use.

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

In my case I always unzip it in the home folder..

So first of all make sure flutter is installed properly:

try to run flutter doctor in a terminal. if that does not work, repeat installation processs following the docs,

if this command works: check that you have all the checks, if not post a picture under this answer I will reply back to you.

If this error is happening on android studio, you need to click on settings in android studio(make sure you have installed the plugins already(Dart and flutter plugins in there)..
[image]

I would recommend doing this after creating a project using: flutter create **myprojectName** .., (if flutter doctor works properly of course) then try opening that project with android studio, and then you will realized from there if is properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings -> Languages & Framework -> Flutter` then you will see bellow screen

Select the folder that contains your `Flutter` `SDK`

After selecting your folder click `Apply` and then click `ok` button.

Enjoy your Flutter Development.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same problem faced me when I start new flutter project then I run **Flutter doctor** and it started updating Dart SDK then it automatically update the location!