# Flutter is not found path below in Mac OS

Tags: android, flutter

Flutter has an error one point as blow

Flutter doctor

Android Studio
✗ Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio/Contents

```
[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /path/to/android/studio/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio/Contents
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.27.0-9.0.pre.37, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15
    darwin-x64, locale en-KH)
    • Flutter version 1.27.0-9.0.pre.37 at /Users/xxx/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 90c66f5db3 (4 days ago), 2021-02-22 18:21:03 -0800
    • Engine revision 07afcf7d0f
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-52.0.dev)


✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at:
      
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
    • All Android licenses accepted.
```

Comment: Can you add more information about your error?

Comment: what more Info that you need ?

Comment: Are you installed Android Studio in this folder?

Comment: I have installed android studio at this path. /Library/Android/sdk/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52259764/flutter-sdk-is-not-found-in-the-specified-location-in-android-studio

Comment: please find edit info above for your reference.
Android Studio not found at /path/to/android/studio/Contents

Comment: This link might help you out [Finding Android SDK on Mac and adding to PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34532063/13829291)

Comment: Mayor Agarwal you are right